# Removing numbers and : from inside a bracket in R

Tags: r

I want to remove only the numbers and : from inside of the following

- input: `AC1(d12:20)-OH`
- output: `AC1(d)-OH`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `regex` like this:

```r
library(stringr) 
x <- "AC1(d12:20)-OH" 
str_replace(x, "(?<=\\()[^)]+", function(m) str_remove_all(m, "[\\d:]"))
# [1] "AC1(d)-OH"
```

### Explanation

- `str_replace` replaces strings based on a Regular Expression
- `(?<=\\()` reads as "find a `(` but do not include it in the match" (look behind)
- `[^)]+` reads as "find a string of maximal length not including `)`
- That is we first match everything **within** the brackets, but exclude the opening bracket from the match thanks to the look behind
- Finally, we use a replacement function in `str_replace` which is called for each match (remember, everything **within** the brackets is our match):

  - Here we use `str_remove_all` to remove **all** of our matches
  - `[\\d:]` reads as "either a number or a `:`"
  - That is wihtin our brackets we remove **all** numebrs and colons